# some basic features do not work in table.el with org mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I will change to table.el in org when merged cell feature needed. But some basic features in org table do not work in table.el. e.g.

1. link to something, i.e. [[chapter1][chapter1]]
2. latex i.e. $x_{i}$
3. Calc and Elisp formulas

correct me if I was wrong, or any help to solve part of above issues?

Comment: links can be inserted with `C-c C-l` -> `(org-insert-link)` .. I think

Comment: @manandearth does not work.

Comment: table.el tables are definitely second-class citizens: `org-element-table-parser` says `;; Only 'org' tables have contents.  'table.el' tables use a ':value' property to store raw table as a string.` In other words, the contents of table.el tables are opaque to just about all of org.